# Servlet returns data from database only once after deployment

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

I'm building a web portal and i'm using Hibernate to access MySQL and push the data fetched to a JSP to print it in a tabular form. I'm using Tomcat for servlet deployment. my servlet has to make 3 HQL queries and then push the data retrieved to the JSP. after i deploy the servlet,it works fine the first time i make a query using HTML form. moreover,in the Eclipse console,i can see all the 3 HQL queries being executed. but when i try to make a query again, even the same query as last time from my HTML form, I dont get any data on the JSP page(the table i was trying to fill contains only zeroes). checking the Eclipse console,i found that only the first HQL query was executed,and nothing else comes up,not even an error message. If i restart Tomcat,or just redeploy the servlet,it works,but only once again. please help

The flow is like-
HTML form -> Servlet -> JSP

```
         String major,date,minor,ip;
         double[][][] transactionTime = new double[2][50][10];
         int[] testCaseId = new int[10];
         String[] activityName = new String[10];
         major=req.getParameter("major");
         date=req.getParameter("date");
         minor=req.getParameter("minor");
         ip=req.getParameter("ip");
         String testCaseName=req.getParameter("testCaseName");
         Session session = null;


      try{

      SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 

    Configuration().configure()
    .buildSessionFactory();
      session =sessionFactory.openSession();

      //Create Select Clause HQL


         String SQL_QUERY2 ="Select testCases.activityName,testCases.testCaseID from TestCases testCases where testCases.testcaseName like \'" + testCaseName + "\'";
         Query query2 = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY2);
         for(Iterator it2=query2.iterate();it2.hasNext();ctr2++)
              {
              Object[] act = (Object[]) it2.next();
              activityName[ctr2]=(String) act[0];
              testCaseId[ctr2] = (Integer) act[1];
              }


        for(int j=0;j<ctr2;j++){
            ctr=0;
         String SQL_QUERY3 ="Select tran.transactionTime from Transactions tran where tran.samples.builds.buildMajorVersion like " + major + " and tran.samples.builds.buildMinorVersion like " + minor + " and tran.samples.runDate like \'" + date + "\' and tran.testCases.testCaseID like " + testCaseId[j] + " and tran.samples.testbeds.server.ipv4Address like \'" + ip + "\'";
         Query query3 = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY3);
         for(Iterator it3=query3.iterate();it3.hasNext();ctr++)
              {
              Object time = (Object) it3.next();
              transactionTime[0][j][ctr]=(Double) time;
              int precision = 100;
              transactionTime[0][j][ctr] = Math.floor(transactionTime[0][j][ctr]*precision+0.5)/precision;
              }
        }



        for(int j=0;j<ctr2;j++){
            ctr3=0;
         String SQL_QUERY5 ="Select tran.transactionTime from Transactions tran where tran.samples.builds.buildMajorVersion like " + major + " and tran.samples.builds.buildMinorVersion like " + minor + " and tran.samples.baseline=1";
         Query query5 = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY5);
         for(Iterator it5=query5.iterate();it5.hasNext();ctr3++)
              {
              Object time = (Object) it5.next();
              transactionTime[1][j][ctr3]=(Double) time;
              int precision = 100;
              transactionTime[1][j][ctr3] = Math.floor(transactionTime[1][j][ctr3]*precision+0.5)/precision;
              }
        }





 session.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
      finally{

      }







    req.setAttribute("major",major);
    req.setAttribute("minor",minor);
    req.setAttribute("date",date);
    req.setAttribute("ip",ip);
    req.setAttribute("testCaseName",testCaseName);
    req.setAttribute("transactionTime", transactionTime);
    req.setAttribute("activityName", activityName);
    req.setAttribute("sampleNumBase", ctr3);
    req.setAttribute("sampleNumRun", ctr);
      req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/src/BaselineRawData.jsp").forward(req, res);  
 }
```

}

Console output in Eclipse on First and successful run

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        testcases0_.activityName as col_0_0_,
        testcases0_.testCaseID as col_1_0_ 
    from
        TestCases testcases0_ 
    where
        testcases0_.testcaseName like 'Deploy 200 tunings on 10 devices with 0 tunings' Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 1
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 2
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 3
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 4
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 5
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ cross 
    join
        TestBeds testbeds7_ cross 
    join
        Machines server8_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and samples1_.testBedId=testbeds7_.testBedId 
        and testbeds7_.serverId=server8_.machineId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and (
            samples1_.runDate like '2012-02-25'
        ) 
        and (
            transactio0_.testCaseId like 6
        ) 
        and (
            server8_.ipv4Address like '10.104.52.200'
        ) Hibernate: 
    select
        transactio0_.transactionTime as col_0_0_ 
    from
        Transactions transactio0_ cross 
    join
        Samples samples1_ cross 
    join
        Builds builds2_ 
    where
        transactio0_.sampleId=samples1_.sampleId 
        and samples1_.buildId=builds2_.buildId 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMajorVersion like 4
        ) 
        and (
            builds2_.buildMinorVersion like 4434
        ) 
        and samples1_.baseline=1 10
```

Console output in Eclipse on Subsequent and unsuccessful runs

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        testcases0_.activityName as col_0_0_,
        testcases0_.testCaseID as col_1_0_ 
    from
        TestCases testcases0_ 
    where
        testcases0_.testcaseName like 'Deploy 200 tunings on 10 devices with 0 tunings'
10
```

Comment: paste the code snippet of servlet.

Comment: what happens if you refresh HTMl page and then submit form again.

Comment: the same thing,no result. because I'm using GET to submit the data, it should have been possible to reload the data just by reloading the page. but neither that works,nor resubmitting the HTML form

Comment: Check out are you getting values on subsequent form submit.Try new values than previous

Comment: Did you debug it? Is it going inside servlet or not?

Comment: @Hardik, yes tried that,the same problem

Comment: @Ram, yes it is,I'll print the console outputs for both first(successful) run and subsequent runs

Comment: First HQL might be returning blank list...check the whether any exception or parameter is submitter second time.

Comment: @GauravSuman : I meant request parameter values. Print them in console. Better provide html code to call servlet.

Comment: Apart from your problem, It is not good to create session factory each time.

Comment: @Hardik, as can be seen in the console output(even during the unsuccessful calls), the value of testcaseName has been successfully passed to the servlet ('Deploy 200 tunings on 10 devices with 0 tunings')

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the parameters i got from the HTML form to the servlet (major,minor,date,ip) are being successfully forwarded to the JSP,its only the database data thats not getting forwarded

Comment: Problem seems with `ctr2`. As your loop iteration are based on that. Where it gets initialized ?

Comment: Thanks Hardik, I had initialised all the ctr variables outside the servlet code,hoping to make them global.so they were not getting initialised when the servlet was being called again. Problem solved :)

Comment: post that comment as an answer to this question so that i can mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardik said
Problem seems with `ctr2`. As your loop iteration are based on that. Where it gets initialized ?

The problem was that `ctr2` and `ctr` were declared and initialised outside d servlet code